# incorrect result with very large integer R

Tags: r, fibonacci

I just coded an algorithm on Fibonacci numbers. R returns a wrong result for:

> 290287121823^2 + 538783

R result is:

> 84266613096281242864828

I'm not doing any comparison here but basic operation.
The result is stored as a numeric. Is there any workaround?
I have options(scipen=999) enabled.

Mathematica gives the correct answer which is:

> 84266613096281243382112

Comment: Did you declare it as int64?

Comment: @Missy I tried but without success since the package is deprecated https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/int64/index.html